# issue in IsCompleted property of async function

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to track when async function gets completed so I tried as given in code
Its not working properly, Have anyone used IsCompleted property of async function.

My code:

```
public async Task SetAsyncTask() 
{ 
//do a long process 
} 

//Calling method 
if (SetAsyncTask().IsCompleted) 
{ 
//display a finish message 
}
```

Please help what is the best way to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either the `await` keyword or use `while` instead of `if`.

```
await SetAsyncTask();
DisplayFinishMessage();
```

or

```
var x = SetAsyncTask();
while (!x.IsCompleted) {}
DisplayFinishMessage();
```

The first option is probably better.

Comment: with await how can I know when this async function going to be finished?

Comment: The code that is after (below) the await keyword will get executed after the function has executed.

Comment: The first option is a lot better as it won't consume the thread during a long running operation.

Comment: the execution is still going on of SetAsyncTask() and without its completion its executing DisplayFinishMessage();

Comment: I was using the same as first option but SetAsyncTask() is consuming lots of time and execution is getting switch to second function. I want to make sure on first async call then show finished message. Also want to know , is it good to use IsCompleted?

Comment: There's really no reason to use IsCompleted. No code after the await statement will execute until the task is complete.

Comment: @Jeff: I agree, but I wanted to point out that that is also possible.

Comment: Possible, but not equivalent :)

Comment: I didn't mean it was equivalent. :)

Answer (score 6):

IsCompleted is not blocking, you want to `await SetAsyncTask();`.

Comment: I want to display message when this async function gets completed.

Comment: If you do MessageBox.Show after the await, execution will return there and show the message box once the async method returns.  Await is like a bookmark that says come back here when this method is done.